# Upgraded ram causing boot/ubuntu problems

Tags: ram, reboot

I upgraded my acer aspire 5 from 8gb ram to 20gb (replaced 4gb ram stick w. 16gb). Replaced w. Kingston DDR4, same clockspeed as the last.

The acer logo only used to show for a split second, now shows for roughly 8 seconds before going to grub.

Then when i boot ubuntu 17.10 and log in I can click on chromium but it wont start. When I click on show application icon it seems to reboot ubuntu/log me out. Then when i log in again the screen flickers and reboots again to log screen.

The guy at shop who replaced ram said it should be a bit slower on first run but this is a different problem. One the first run things were fine and the ram was recognised. Now it's not working...

Any suggestions to what might be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Which model of Acer Aspire?  Do you know for sure that a 16GB stick is specifically allowed for your model?  Since it is usually recommended that when using two ram sticks, that they match in both speed and capacity (and your config doesn't) have you tried testing with ONLY the 16GB stick (assuming it's permitted on your model)?

Comment: The guys at the shop replaced it so assumed the knew what they were doing, maybe silly to assume... It's an acer A515-51G-50LA. There is a 4gb hard built in ram and was a 4gb removeable ram, only one slot. Apparently the laptop can take up to 20GB ram.

Comment: According to crucial, you are correct about the max memory (https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Acer/aspire-a515-51g).  What I would do is remove the stick and see if it will boot normally... that would prove it is related to the new stick.  Additionally, did you go into the bios and confirm it sees the correct amount of RAM.. ??  I did see something in the manual that mentions a "memory mismatch error", the cure of which was to go into the BIOS (via F2) and then save and exit from it and reboot.

Comment: Okay thanks tony ill try this and get back to you

Comment: Okay so I took it out and it's working fine. When I went into bios it says that it is like 20480MB of ram so maybe because it's a little over... I saved from bios and nothing happened. The stick I'm using is also a Micron (crucial by micron), which is the one I took out.

Comment: This is the new ram stick: https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/aspire-a515-51g/CT10715739

Comment: When I take it out (16gb) then put it back in it works fine again... Not sure what to think...

Comment: So it's working with the 16gb stick in it..??  If so, then it sounds like going into the BIOS and "saving" worked.

Comment: My apologies - it wasnt in properly. No, it does the same (freeze and bug out) when the card is in.

Comment: The only other thing I could think of is your BIOS may need to be updated... failing that I would take it back to the shop that you bought the memory and paid to have it installed.